# mensagem de erro ao tentar remover arquivo

Tags: linux

Quando executo o comando

```
root@debian-hy:/var/www/sys# rm teste.txt
rm: cannot remove `teste.txt': Operation not permitted
```

Estranho porque eu consigo editar o arquivo e salvar, mas quando eu fecho o vi ele gera um arquivo swap, segue as permissões dos arquivos:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root        6 May 21 08:31 teste.tx~
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root      12K May 21 08:31 teste_tx.swn
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root      12K May 21 08:31 teste_tx.swo
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root     4.0K May 21 08:26 teste_tx.swp
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root       12 May 21 08:31 teste.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root        0 May 21 08:26 .teste.txt.swp
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root        0 May 21 08:26 .teste.txt.swx
```

Comment: Se quando você fecha o vi ele gera um `.swp`, então você não consegue editar o arquivo. (consegue só ler). Quais os outputs dos comandos `lsattr teste.txt` e `echo $UID $EUID`?

Comment: @fonini eu nem conhecia esse comando lsattr, foi pesquisando esse comando que eu consegui resolver o problema, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei uma documentação ref. aos comandos **lsattr** e **chattr**

O comando **chattr** serve para incrementar segurança no arquivo ou diretório, o comando ele usa **atributos** e não **permissão** como o **chmod**, esses atributos são extensões que não deixa o arquivo ser removido, alterado ou renomeado dependendo dos parametros usados, esses atributos pode ser atribuídos para o dono do arquivo e até mesmo para o **root**

quando eu executei o comando:

```
root@debian-hy:/var/www/sys# lsattr -d teste.txt
-----a------------- teste.txt
```

Esse "a" indica que o arquivo pode ser incrementado ou seja adicionar mais texto no final do arquivo, mas não pode ser renomeado ou deletado.

Então usei o comando:

```
root@debian-hy:/var/www/sys# chattr -a teste.txt
root@debian-hy:/var/www/sys# lsattr -a teste.txt
------------------- teste.txt
```

Note que usei o comando **lsattr** para ver os atríbutos novamente e dessa vez o arquivo não possui mais nenhum atríbuto, então agora ele pode ser removido.

> http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Comandos-chattr-e-lsattr

Comment: Quero deixar meu obrigado ao Sr. EduardoFernandes e o @fonini, pela dedicação, eu mesmo já tinha desistido de mexer nesse diretório que estava "trancado"

Answer (score 1):

Execute a operação com sudo: `sudo rm teste.txt`

Caso isso não funcione, execute as seguintes operações:

```
sudo chown root teste.txt
sudo chmod 777 teste.txt
sudo rm teste.txt
```

Comment: root@debian-hy:/var/www/sys# sudo rm teste.txt
-bash: sudo: command not found
(usando debian 7 )

Comment: Você executou: `sudo rm teste.txt`  ???? Qual Linux você usa?

Comment: sim @EduardoFernandes o comentário acima ficou meio ruim de ler mas esta ali o comando e o retorno do comando executado e em parenteses a distribuição que uso
<br/>
root@debian-hy:/var/www/sys# sudo rm teste.txt
<br/>
 -bash: sudo: command not found
<br/>
(usando debian 7 )

Comment: Note que se você não tem disponível o comando `sudo` algo está muito errado com sua instalação Linux.

Comment: eu instalei o comando sudo via apt-get agora a mensagem que da é essa "rm: cannot remove `teste.txt': Operation not permitted"

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Veja, por favor, se lhe ajuda.